# C++ Help Array and Function

Tags: c++, arrays, function

First time poster. I am writing a program to calculate federal income tax.  The user is to enter a status code (1,2,3,4) to represent a filing status. I am to write a function for this, to get the tax income, to calculate the tax amount and to display the results.  I also am using to two one dimensional arrays for the tax rates and the filing status.  What I have written so far is posted.  Any help is appreciated.
        Why am I getting the errors?  How can I fix the functions and arrays?

```
 #include <iostream>
    #include <cmath>
    #include <iomanip>
    #include <string>

    using namespace std;

    int getStatusCode();  // function declaration
    float calcTaxAmt();
    void displayResults();
    float getTaxIncome();


    std:int getStatusCode()                        // status code function and array
    {
    std:string filingStatus[4] = { "Single", "Married Filing Jointly", "Married filing Seperately", "Head of Household" };
        bool statusCode = false;

        do {
            cout << "Enter your filing status: " << endl;
            for (int i = 0; i < size(filingStatus); i++;)
            {
                cout << "Enter '" << i + 1 << "' for " << filingStatus[i] << "." << endl;
            }
            cin >> statusCode;
            cout << "\nWhen you are finished, please press '9'.\n" << endl;

            cin >> statusCode = 9;

            while (statusCode != 9) {

                while (statusCode < 1 || (statusCode > 4 && statusCode != 9));

                if (statusCode != 9) {
                    do {

                        cout << "\nEnter your income for the past year: \n" << endl;                            // do while statement to input income
                        cin >> taxableIncome;

                        if (taxableIncome < 500) {
                            cout << "\nYour income is less than $500.  You do not owe any taxes.\n" << endl;    // message if user's income is less than $500
                        }

                    } while (taxableIncome < 500);

                    return 
                    {

                        float calcTaxAmount(int statusCode, float taxableIncome) {
                            float taxAmt;

                            switch (statusCode)                                                                         // switch statement to compute taxes owed
                            {

                            case 1:                                                                                     // Filing single
                                if (taxableIncome <= 7550) {
                                    taxAmt = (taxableIncome)* (float)(.10);
                                    cout << "\nThe amount of taxes you owe is:" << taxAmt << endl;
                                }
                                else if (taxableIncome > 7550 && taxableIncome < 30650) {
                                    taxAmt = 7550 * (float)(.10) + (taxableIncome - 7550)  * (float)(.16);
                                    cout << "\nThe amount of taxes you owe is:" << taxAmt << endl;
                                }
                                else if (taxableIncome > 30650 && taxableIncome < 74200) {
                                    taxAmt = 7550 * (float)(.10) + (30650 - 7550) * (float)(.16) + (taxableIncome - 30650) * (float)(.26);
                                    cout << "\nThe amount of taxes you owe is:" << taxAmt << endl;
                                }
                                else if (taxableIncome > 74200 && taxableIncome < 154800) {
                                    taxAmt = 7550 * (float)(.10) + (30650 - 7550) * (float)(.16) + (74200 - 30650) * (float)(.26) + (taxableIncome - 74200)* (float)(.30);
                                    cout << "\nThe amount of taxes you owe is:" << taxAmt << endl;
                                }
                                else if (taxableIncome > 154800 && taxableIncome < 336550) {
                                    taxAmt = 7550 * (float)(.10) + (30650 - 7550) * (float)(.16) + (74200 - 30650) * (float)(.26) + (154800 - 74200) * (float)(.30) + (taxableIncome - 154800) * (float)(.33);
                                    cout << "\nThe amount of taxes you owe is:" << taxAmt << endl;
                                }
                                else if (taxableIncome > 336550) {
                                    taxAmt = 7550 * (float)(.10) + (30650 - 7550) * (float)(.16) + (74200 - 30650) * (float)(.26) + (154800 - 74200) * (float)(.30) + (336550 - 154800) * (float)(.33) + (taxableIncome - 336550)* (float)(.38);
                                    cout << "\nThe amount of taxes you owe is:" << taxAmt << endl;

                                }


                                break;


                            case 2:                                                                                     // Married filing jointly
                                if (taxableIncome <= 15100) {
                                    taxAmt = (taxableIncome)* (float)(.10);
                                    cout << "\nThe amount of taxes you owe is: " << taxAmt << endl;
                                }
                                else if (taxableIncome > 15100 && taxableIncome < 61300) {
                                    taxAmt = 15100 * (float)(.10) + (taxableIncome - 15100) * (float)(.16);
                                    cout << "\nThe amount of taxes you owe is:" << taxAmt << endl;
                                }
                                else if (taxableIncome > 61300 && taxableIncome < 123700) {
                                    taxAmt = 15100 * (float)(.10) + (61300 - 15100)* (float)(.16) + (taxableIncome - 61300)* (float)(.26);
                                    cout << "\nThe amount of taxes you owe is:" << taxAmt << endl;
                                }
                                else if (taxableIncome > 123700 && taxableIncome < 188450) {
                                    taxAmt = 15100 * (float)(.10) + (61300 - 15100)* (float)(.16) + (123700 - 61300)*(float)(.26) + (taxableIncome - 123700)* (float)(.30);
                                    cout << "\nThe amount of taxes you owe is: " << taxAmt << endl;
                                }
                                else if (taxableIncome > 188450 && taxableIncome < 336550) {
                                    taxAmt = 15100 * (float)(.10) + (61300 - 15100)* (float)(.16) + (123700 - 61300)*(float)(.26) + (188450 - 123700) + (taxableIncome - 188450)* (float)(.33);
                                    cout << "\nThe amount of taxes you owe is: " << taxAmt << endl;
                                }
                                else if (taxableIncome > 336550) {
                                    taxAmt = 15100 * (float)(.10) + (61300 - 15100)* (float)(.16) + (123700 - 61300)*(float)(.26) + (188450 - 123700) + (336550 - 188450) * (float)(.33) + (taxableIncome - 336550)* (float)(.38);
                                    cout << "\nThe amount of taxes you owe is: " << taxAmt << endl;
                                }
                                break;


                            case 3:                                                                                                     // Married filing seperately
                                if (taxableIncome <= 7550) {
                                    taxAmt = taxableIncome * (float)(.10);
                                    cout << "\nThe amount of taxes you owe is: " << taxAmt << endl;
                                }
                                else if (taxableIncome > 7550 && taxableIncome < 30650) {
                                    taxAmt = 7550 * (float)(.10) + (taxableIncome - 7550) * (float)(.16);
                                    cout << "\nThe amount of taxes you owe is: " << taxAmt << endl;
                                }
                                else if (taxableIncome > 30650 && taxableIncome < 61850) {
                                    taxAmt = 7550 * (float)(.10) + (30650 - 7550) * (float)(.16) + (taxableIncome - 30650) * (float)(.26);
                                    cout << "\nThe amount of taxes you owe is: " << taxAmt << endl;
                                }
                                else if (taxableIncome > 61850 && taxableIncome < 94225) {
                                    taxAmt = 7550 * (float)(.10) + (30650 - 7550) * (float)(.16) + (61850 - 30650) * (float)(.26) + (taxableIncome - 61850) * (float)(.30);
                                    cout << "\nThe amount of taxes you owe is: " << taxAmt << endl;
                                }
                                else if (taxableIncome > 94226 && taxableIncome < 168275) {
                                    taxAmt = 7550 * (float)(.10) + (30650 - 7550) * (float)(.16) + (61850 - 30650) * (float)(.26) + (94226 - 61850) * (float)(.30) + (taxableIncome - 94226) * (float)(.33);
                                    cout << "\nThe amount of taxes you owe is: " << taxAmt << endl;
                                }
                                else if (taxableIncome > 168276) {
                                    taxAmt = 7550 * (float)(.10) + (30650 - 7550) * (float)(.16) + (61850 - 30650) * (float)(.26) + (94226 - 61850) * (float)(.30) + (168276 - 94226) * (float)(.33) + (taxableIncome - 168276)* (float)(.38);
                                    cout << "\nThe amount of taxes you owe is: " << taxAmt << endl;
                                }
                                break;


                            case 4:                                                                                             // Head of household
                                if (taxableIncome <= 10750) {
                                    taxAmt = taxableIncome * (float)(.10);
                                    cout << "\nThe amount of taxes you owe is: " << taxAmt << endl;
                                }
                                else if (taxableIncome > 10750 && taxableIncome < 41050) {
                                    taxAmt = 10750 * (float)(.10) + (taxableIncome - 10750)* (float)(.16);
                                    cout << "\nThe amount of taxes you owe is: " << taxAmt << endl;
                                }
                                else if (taxableIncome > 41050 && taxableIncome < 106000) {
                                    taxAmt = 10750 * (float)(.10) + (41050 - 10750)* (float)(.16) + (taxableIncome - 41050)* (float)(.26);
                                    cout << "\nThe amount of taxes you owe is: " << taxAmt << endl;
                                }
                                else if (taxableIncome > 106000 && taxableIncome < 171650) {
                                    taxAmt = 10750 * (float)(.10) + (41050 - 10750)* (float)(.16) + (106000 - 41050)* (float)(.26) + (taxableIncome - 106000)* (float)(.30);
                                    cout << "\nThe amount of taxes you owe is: " << taxAmt << endl;
                                }
                                else if (taxableIncome > 171650 && taxableIncome < 336550) {
                                    taxAmt = 10750 * (float)(.10) + (41050 - 10750)* (float)(.16) + (106000 - 41050)* (float)(.26) + (171650 - 106000)* (float)(.30) + (taxableIncome - 171650)* (float)(.33);
                                    cout << "\nThe amount of taxes you owe is: " << taxAmt << endl;
                                }
                                else if (taxableIncome > 336550) {
                                    taxAmt = 10750 * (float)(.10) + (41050 - 10750)* (float)(.16) + (106000 - 41050)* (float)(.26) + (171650 - 106000)* (float)(.30) + (336550 - 171650)* (float)(.33) + (taxableIncome - 336550)* (float)(.38);
                                    cout << "\nThe amount of taxes you owe is: " << taxAmt << endl;
                                }
                                break;

                            }

                        }
                    }
                    return taxAmt;

                }

    int main() {

        int statusCode;                                                         // variables
        float taxableIncome;
        float taxAmt;
        float taxRate[6] = { .10, .16, .26, .30, .33, .38 };    // tax rate array       

    system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Could you post the errors that you are getting from the code? This can help figure us out possible bugs in the code.

Comment: These are the error codes I am getting,1>MSVCRTD.lib(crtexe.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup
 : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Comment: The way to write code is to start with something small and simple that works perfectly, then add complexity a little at a time, testing at every step, and **never add to code that doesn't work.** In this case you have a linking error, so you should try writing something simple that involves linking to a library (or whatever you're trying to do). Small steps.

Comment: Always look at the _first_ error, or you'll go off in the wrong direction.  I imagine this link error is the result of attempting to link an object that wasn't built due to earlier errors.  For example, the code you posted has syntax errors like `std:int`, along with what could easily be nesting errors (not verified, but the code has serious layout issues that could easily lead to this) and other crazy things like using a whole scope block as a return value.

Comment: I think the linker error is a red herring.  I get a slew of compiler errors with your code.  For example, what's `std:int`?  Also, what's `cin >> statusCode = 9;`?  Neither of those are valid syntax.

Comment: cin >> statusCode = 9 is suppose to allow the user to exit the program when they press 9.  This is a modification from an earlier program that did run but just used a do/while loop and switch statements.

Comment: @newbie: That doesn't work.  The `>>` operator has higher precedence than the `=` operator, so it tries to assign `9` to `cin`.  As the answer below suggests, you need to take a step back and add a little code at a time until it compiles without error before moving on to the next step.

Comment: @newbie: I tried to compile your code and there seems to very trivial coding and syntax mistakes in your code. I would recommend you to read more about C++ language syntax before jumping into the coding.

Answer (score 1):

The error you posted is happening because the compiler can't find main. This happens because you opened more curly braces than you closed. Also I won't say too much about your coding style, but here are a few more things that are horribly wrong:

```
std:int getStatusCode()
```

There is no need for `std:` here, whatever that should do.

```
std:string
```

This should be std::string, it's a namespace, not a goto label or something. You even used `using namespace std;` at the beginning.

The rest of the errors probably occur since you didnt close all of the curly braces. Also notice that you provide the declaration for

```
void displayResults();
float getTaxIncome();
```

but you don't provide an implementation.

Also this doesn't make any sense, I also don't really know what you are trying to do there:

```
cin >> statusCode = 9;
```

Also there is a return without a semicolon in line 46.

```
while (statusCode < 1 || (statusCode > 4 && statusCode != 9));
```

This while loop doesn't have a body...

```
for (int i = 0; i < size(filingStatus); i++;)
```

Also there is no `size` function for arrays, just use a 4 instead, it's a simple array and you know the size. And there shouldn't be a semicolon after i++.

It doesn't make any sense to search for more errors, start with a simple project and learn the basics of C++. This code is just a total mess and should not be posted on stackoverflow.